# Help with a diagonalization proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need a bit of help with proving, using diagonalization, the following theorem:
The set of all infinite binary sequences that do not contain that sequence $00$ is uncountable.
Now, I know I should assume there's an enumeration of the set, and then find an infinite binary sequence $S$ that doesn't contain $00$, so that for any $S_n$ in the enumeration, $S(n) \neq S_n(n)$. The problem is I have no idea of how to construct such $S$ using the enumeration.
Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at terms two at a time, and do the replacement in a way that ensures you'll never get two 0s in a row, either by always starting with a 1, or always ending with a 1.

Comment: But then how do I ensure the sequence created isn't already in the enumeration?

Comment: Because you are picking a 2-digit sequence that differs from the one you are looking at. Same as in the usual diagonal argument.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use a different argument, using what's already been proved.

Say $S$ is as above, and let $B$ be the set of all binary strings. Define $\phi(0)=10$ and $\phi(1)=11$. Define $f:B\to S$ by $$f((b_1,b_2,\dots))=(\phi(b_1),\phi(b_2),\dots).$$Show that $f$ is injective; then $B$ uncountable implies $S$ uncountable.